# How Do I Properly Seal/Finish Slate For A Workbench Top

Tags: sealing, finishing, slate

I have two very nice pieces of slate from the remnants of a small pool table. I'd like to cut them to size with my circular saw, using a wet masonry blade, and then seal/finish them to use as a workbench topper, in the style of the old classroom chemistry lab benches.

1. I'm not sure that a product used to seal and finish a slate floor or kitchen countertop is the best choice for this application. What's the ideal product? Something like this [Impregnator](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Miracle-Sealants-511-Impregnator-16-fl-oz-Clear-Natural-Stone-Sealer-and-Finish-Pour-Bottle/1000571523) or [Seal & Enhance](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Miracle-Sealants-MS-511-Seal-and-Enhance-QT/1000566013)? Not asking for a particular product, but there's a lot of different things out there that appear to be for similar purposes, but are labeled differently.
2. What technique do I use to get a very smooth and even finish?

Comment: "Ideal" for what purpose. We don't do product reviews/recommendations here, so as it stands this could get closed for being a product recommendation or opinion based. Also, it's not clear what question 2 is about - a smooth finish when cutting? a smooth finish when sealing? Once you identify what kind of sealant to use, then ask about how to use it (if that's what you're after).  Please [edit] your question to be more specific in what you're asking. TBH, though, I can't fathom why something for a kitchen counter top wouldn't work just fine for a workbench...

Comment: High quality sand paper on a random orbital sander is how I have ground this kind of countertop moving to finer grit for a higher polish, after that a off the shelf granite or quartz countertop sealer would be what I would use and most big box stores carry sealer, don’t go cheep on the sand paper go with wet/dry and the best media aluminum oxide will work but if you can afford quartz it works well if you can find it and afford it that is.

Comment: @EdBeal  This looks like an answer to me. Not a product recommendation but a product type..

Comment: @FreeMan The reason I wasn't sure whether or not the kitchen counter top sealant was appropriate is that the slate finishing work I've seen has intentionally left the texture rougher, for a "rustic" kind of look, and that's not what I'm aiming for; I'd like the finished surface to be as smooth and uniform as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High quality sand paper on a random orbital sander is how I have ground this kind of countertop moving to finer grit for a higher polish.

I have created some nice concrete and turned a rough granite into High gloss smooth countertops.

High quality sand paper on a random orbital sander is the key, to grind this kind of countertop moving to finer grit(s)for a higher polish just enough water to keep the dust in the slurry and extend paper life.

after that a off the shelf granite or quartz countertop sealer would be what I would use and most big box stores carry sealer.

don’t go cheep on the sand paper go with wet/dry and the best media. aluminum oxide will work but if you can afford quartz sometimes called diamond works well if you can find it and afford it that is.

using quality sand paper on a random orbital sander.
I have ground this kind of countertop starting at 400 moving to finer grit to 1200+ for a higher polish.

I can’t say this enough:
Again don’t go cheep on the sand paper go with wet/dry and the best media you can afford it’s worth it.